# Does it matter that my Panty Shot is Naughty?

Tags: one-way-heroics

I'm on my quest to defeat the Dark Lord, and specifically this time I'm bringing the legendary merc Panty Shot along for the ride.  However, he appears to have spawned with the "Naughty" modifier:

[image: Naughty, Naughty Panty!]

(Yes, that is his name.  No I did not pick it.)

I've had a few odd adjectives applied to some of my companions before.  For instance, my King was once Masochistic.  This seemed to give him the chance to...  exclaim, let's say, when he was hit.  Some of the other adjectives are obvious, like "frail."  However, I can't figure out what "Naughty" does.  It doesn't seem to do anything, as far as I can tell.

This is all complicated by the fact that I'm naked.  (Zenura Weave FTW)  I'm a bit uncomfortable with Panty tagging along with my lady bits hanging out.  Can someone tell me if there's something I should be worried about here, or am I just being paranoid for nothing?

Comment: I... this... what.

Comment: According to [this link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/OneWayHeroics) it causes "interesting" dialogue.  So you're probably going to get even more uncomfortable...

Comment: And now just have to wait for this to turn up in the "Hot Network Questions" and for someone to add this to [the list](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/the-master-list-of-questions-which-really-need-context/9714#9714)

Comment: I have no idea what to think about this post...

Comment: @Ethan This Post: Hilarious. The game however, that's the cause for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this is cause for celebration.

From the [wiki](http://onewayheroics.wikia.com/wiki/Prefixes):

- (Can be) Applied to: Ally, NPC and Monsters
- Effect: Defense up; EXP yield up. Ally characters get different conversation text.

The fact that he is also naked has nothing to do with it.

Comment: So Mr. "Panty Shot" is a clothed male NPC.  My character is the naked, female "Hero."

Comment: The "Naughty" Modifier is still the same.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought you might want to correct your answer a bit :)